# Show humberger icon on top right

Tags: material-design-lite

I am using Google's MDL.

I need to have a right aligned hamburger. By default the icon appears on top left.

This the code from MDL page:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
  </main>
</div>
```

I tried changing the direction of div tagss but that didn't help. It is still on the left.

Comment: Using the following procedures, I managed to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32539822/2068444

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material Design Lite (MDL) Navigation Drawer on the right side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131858/material-design-lite-mdl-navigation-drawer-on-the-right-side)